# How can we deploy docker image of rails application in .drone.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, drone.io

I am working on integrating a drone CI/CD with a rails application. As we don't want to make our code public, we can't store/get that image from Docker Hub. So I am working around how I can deploy the docker image of our application in .drone.yml configuration itself. Please suggest to me how I can achieve this if you can give some sample commands and processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're speaking of a single image. In the free plan there's 1 private repository so you don't have to make the code public.

Anyway I think there's some confusion. The dockerhub is where you store the images (it can also perform builds in the paid plans), drone CI builds the images but does not store them.
It does not really matter how you build the image, you need to "push" it somewhere if you plan to "pull" it from other machines. If you don't plan to "pull" it, you can always "save" and "load" the images locally using some bash commands in the drone ci. You can check https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/examples/services/docker_dind/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/ for more info.

Comment: I need to push the docker image to AWS EC2 instance

Comment: you can transfer the resulting tar file via SSH if you want to save some money, you can setup a private docker registry in your AWS network or you can use the AWS ECR (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecr/get-started)

Comment: Ok so in the script tag in drone.yml i am giving 'docker build .' so it can build the docker image and after that we can save that image to a tar file correct

Comment: well the build phase can be done by drone without going via a script but once that phase is done, you have to use `docker save -o myimages-latest.tar myimage1:latest myimage2:latest myimage3:latest`. Then you can transfer the myimages-latest.tar via sftp/s3/something_else on the ec2 instance and there you can use `docker load --input myimages-latest.tar`.

Comment: without going via script..i didnt get it. How can we achieve it

Comment: I just re-read and I'm wrong there. I wanted to write something completely different but it came like that... Sorry. I meant to write that you don't have to script the whole build and deploy phases together.